# How to convert an image in gray scale to an image in black/white but with higher resolution?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, artificial-intelligence, interpolation

I have some text scanned into a gray scale image (say .tiff). I want to reduce its size by converting it to black-white format. But I don't want to introduce too obvious jigsaw effect, so I want to increase the resolution (say new 2x2 pixels for an original 1x1 pixel) by interpolation. What is the proper way to do so in imagemagick or other tools to make the final image still look similar to the original image?

Comment: I do not know if this will do what you want, but you can use -sample or -scale to duplicated pixels when enlarging.  I cannot think of any way right now to split pixels into smaller size when enlarging. You could try -resample to enlarge and then threshold again.

Comment: I think you want some tool that does super resolution processing. That might require AI/Deep Learning with training.

Answer (score 0):

You can do dithering, which is the technique used in GIFs. Areas are replaced by pixel patterns. For instance this:

[image]

Becomes this with a two color colormap:

[image]

Now, if you scale up you aren't adding much information, so compression algorithms will be more efficient on the scaled up image and not produce a 4x bigger file.

An important cause of file size in scanned images is very often noise. You can remove a lot of noise by filtering (median blur is quite good at removing noise without losing sharpness).

Now, maybe just using the proper JPEG compression settings will allow you to keep a decent image quality (grayscale looks better than binary B&W)(because JPEG is a possible compression mode in TIFF)

With [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#monochrome) starting with this:

[image: Source]

```
convert Source.png -scale 200% -monochrome  Dithered-Mono.png
```

Gives this:

[image]

Which is of poor quality for general image (but could be adequate for text scans)

```
convert Source.png -scale 200% -remap pattern:gray50  Dithered-Remap.png
```

Yields this:

[image]

Which is of somewhat better quality.

Finally:

```
convert Source.png -scale 200%  -remap pattern:gray50 -define png:color-type=3 -define png:bit-depth=1 Dithered-1bit.png
```

Gives this:

[image]

Which is of equivalent quality.

The corresponding image sizes are:

```
897573 Source.png

382698 Dithered-1bit.png
217059 Dithered-Mono.png
382681 Dithered-Remap.png
```

So this is pretty close to 1-bit/pixel whatever the encoding.

Side note, if you just use JPEG you get better a better size with much less damage to the image:

```
convert Source.png -quality 80 Unscaled.jpg
```

[image]

```
152786 Unscaled.jpg
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with imagemagick or some easy commands? Or I will need to use a program to do it?

Comment: See augmented answer